# How to influence which authentication method is used against MS ADAL (IWA or Form-based) when using react-adal library?

Tags: reactjs, azure, adal, adal.js

My company's IT department is driving me crazy. Please help:

We have a SAP HANA Cloud hosted react app that is supposed to authenticate against Azure. The current login procedure always seems to use the Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) to determine the user during the login process. As a result the user is automatically logged-in via Single-Sign-on (SSO).

How can I instruct the react-adal library to explicitly request a form-based login, one where Azure is showing it's own login form, rather than using the IWA based on the current Windows user (SSO)?

Is there a way to explicitly state which method to use when trying to establish trust between Azure and SAP HANA Cloud?

Can I influence this from within the react code or is there some configuration on the Azure Plattform necessary?

The app already has its own App-ID, hence the automated login is working.

I spend significant time in the documentation but cannot find any recommendation how to tackle this problem.

Looking forward to any suggestions! I am out of ideas... Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in the ADAL.JS library there is an extra query parameter which can be sent to the Azure endpoint:

```
extraQueryParameter: 'prompt=login'
```